# Error GS026 in 2nd call to execTransaction - GnosisSafe v1.3.0

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core

I'm conducting a PoC in which web3j is used for dealing the GnosisSafe smart contract (SC). In this way, we've successfully deployed the SC, put some ERC20 tokens under its control, added some authorized signers to it, and finally, invoke successfully `execTransaction` for transferring some tokens to a 3rd wallet. The issue happens when I tried a second transferring operation. This time the tx is reverted with the code `GS026`.

I couldn't find any documentation about the GnosisSafe v1.3.0 (any link to it it'd be highly appreciate), so I don't get why the transferring works just one time. Is it required any further step between to transferring (execTransaction) invocations?

Looking forward to any help and many thanks in advance.

This is the code snippet

```
        String encodedFunc = sampleTokenLoaded.transfer(body.getToWalletAddress(), BigInteger.valueOf(body.getAmount() * DECIMALS)).encodeFunctionCall();
        Log.infof("Encoded Func %s", encodedFunc);
        byte[] hash = gnosisSageLoaded.getTransactionHash(
                sampleTokenLoaded.getContractAddress(),
                BigInteger.ZERO,
                Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(encodedFunc),
                BigInteger.ZERO,
                BigInteger.ZERO,
                BigInteger.ZERO,
                BigInteger.ZERO,
                "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", BigInteger.ZERO).send();

        List<Credentials> signerCreds = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String signerWalletKeyRef : body.getSignerWalletKeyRefs()) {
            var signerKeyPair = getKeyInfo(signerWalletKeyRef);
            var signerHsmEcKeyPair = HsmEcKeyPair.create(signerKeyPair, koreTsbClient);
            signerCreds.add(Credentials.create(signerHsmEcKeyPair));
        }
        signerCreds.sort(Comparator.comparing(Credentials::getAddress));

        byte[] retval = new byte[65 * signerCreds.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for (Credentials signerCred : signerCreds) {
            Sign.SignatureData signature = Sign.signMessage(hash, signerCred.getEcKeyPair(), false);
            System.arraycopy(signature.getR(), 0, retval, 0 + (65 * index), 32);
            System.arraycopy(signature.getS(), 0, retval, 32 + (65 * index), 32);
            System.arraycopy(signature.getV(), 0, retval, 64 + (65 * index), 1);
            Log.infof("Signatures %s", Numeric.toHexString(retval));
            index++;
        }

        var receipt = gnosisSageLoaded.execTransaction(sampleTokenLoaded.getContractAddress(),
                BigInteger.ZERO, Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(encodedFunc), BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ZERO,
                "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", retval, BigInteger.ZERO).send();
```

Kind regards,

Roque

Comment: I don't know anything about gnosis but it seems you have a typo here: `var receipt = gnosisSageLoaded.`

Answer (score 0):

The [error code](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/docs/error_codes.md) `GS026` corresponds to the message `Invalid owner provided`. You should be able to execute multiple transactions in a row (as long as they have time to be processed by the blockchain in the correct order), so I suggest the error comes from the call itself.

Even though we don't currently have specific documentation about v1.3.0, you can have a look at [this example](https://github.com/5afe/safe-core-protocol-demo/) on how to interact with Safe protocol contracts.

Hope it helps!
Louis